# Error: ValueError when using PySpark's month and dayofmonth functions in DataFrame boolean expression

Tags: pyspark

I want to write a function which will satisfy following condition:-
The logic you are trying to achieve is as follows:

1. Check if the month of the sddgl column is equal to 12 and the day of the month is equal to 26.
2. If the condition is true, add one day to the sddgl column using the date_add function and update the sddgl column with the new value.
3. If the condition is false, leave the sddgl column unchanged.

I tried following :-

```
def sales_logic(sales_data):

    if (f.month(sales_data["sddgl"]==12)) & (f.dayofmonth(sales_data["sddgl"]==26)):
        sales_data["sddgl"]=date_add(sales_data["sddgl"],1)
    else:
        sales_data["sddgl"]
    # group_by=sales_data.groupBy("sddcto","sddgl","aiac23","aiac23_udc","schnl","schnl_ecom","bu_schnl","bu_schnl_name",sdco)
    return sales_data
```

But I got this error:- ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

How should i solve it?

Comment: Where do you use this function? also, notice that in the else you do not assign any value or doing anything with the column, you can just remove the else section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign columns like that in pyspark. Also, your braces are wrong. Try using the when/otherwise construction:

```
sales_data = sales_data.withColumn("sddgl", 
    f.when(
        (f.month(sales_data["sddgl"])==12) & 
        (f.dayofmonth(sales_data["sddgl"])==26), date_add(sales_data["sddgl"],1)
    ).otherwise(sales_data["sddgl"])
```